# Oracle updating data with iterator

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a mistake in updating some records and need some help in "restoring" them. I the following data, I need the EC and INVOICE_NUM KEYWORDs to have an iterator suffix like in the desired results shown below.

How can I iterate through all my records and do this for each RID that has > 1 VALUE for the EC and INVOICE_NUM KEYWORDs? If there is only one EC or INVOICE_NUM, it doesn't need to be updated, it can stay as EC or INVOICE_NUM.

On Production:

```
RID       KEYWORD        VALUE
692307    BANK_NUM       17                         
692307    CHECK_AMT      $ 2504.62                  
692307    CHECK_DT       71121                   
692307    CHECK_NUM      27034                      
692307    DOC_NAME       Expense-Check              
692307    EC             71103CTRC               
692307    EC             71027TNRF               
692307    EC             71114TXWCS              
692307    EC             71117TXCP               
692307    EC             7111ONJAD               
692307    FILENAME       Q:\teleform\00028076\0     
692307    INVOICE_NUM    2193000086                 
692307    INVOICE_NUM    9190000875                 
692307    INVOICE_NUM    9600010418                 
692307    INVOICE_NUM    9600010414                 
692307    INVOICE_NUM    8100000372                 
692307    VEND_NAME      KINKO'S INC.               
692307    VEND_NUM       1002838
```

Desired Results:

```
RID       KEYWORD        VALUE
692307    BANK_NUM       17                    
692307    CHECK_AMT      $ 2504.62             
692307    CHECK_DT       71121              
692307    CHECK_NUM      27034                 
692307    DOC_NAME       Expense-Check         
692307    EC_1           71103CTRC          
692307    EC_2           71027TNRF          
692307    EC_3           71114TXWCS         
692307    EC_4           71117TXCP          
692307    EC_5           7111ONJAD          
692307    FILENAME       Q:\teleform\00028076\0
692307    INVOICE_NUM_1  9190000875            
692307    INVOICE_NUM_2  2193000086            
692307    INVOICE_NUM_3  9600010418            
692307    INVOICE_NUM_4  9600010414            
692307    INVOICE_NUM_5  8100000372            
692307    VEND_NAME      KINKO'S INC.          
692307    VEND_NUM       1002838
```

Ditto's query results:

```
RID         ORIGINAL_KEYWORD    VALUE           NEW_KEYWORD
3361978    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_1
3361979    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_2
3361980    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_3
3361981    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_4
3361982    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_5
3361983    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_6
3361984    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_7
3361985    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_8
3361986    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_9
3361987    DOC_NAME             Expense-Check    DOC_NAME_10
```

*** More Updates ***

```
RID        KEYWORD          VALUE
5716220    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716220    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 3797.68             
5716220    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716220    CHECK_NUMBER     67714                 
5716220    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141107NVCC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141107NVCC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141113FLRC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141031INRA            
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141107MSAM            
5716220    EVENT_CODE       141113SCRCO           
5716220    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133619\0
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   DB791094              
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   791094                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   792456                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   789983                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   791910                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER   792452                
5716220    VENDOR_NAME      VTECH                 
5716220    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001685               

5716221    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716221    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 3797.68             
5716221    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716221    CHECK_NUMBER     67714                 
5716221    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716221    EVENT_CODE       141113SCRCO           
5716221    EVENT_CODE       141113AZRAR           
5716221    EVENT_CODE       141104MORER           
5716221    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133619\1
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER   792959                
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER   792508                
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER   790437                
5716221    VENDOR_NAME      VTECH                 
5716221    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001685               

5716222    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716222    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 7782.73             
5716222    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716222    CHECK_NUMBER     67711                 
5716222    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716222    EVENT_CODE                             
5716222    EVENT_CODE                             
5716222    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133616\0
5716222    INVOICE_NUMBER   150562                
5716222    INVOICE_NUMBER   150533                
5716222    VENDOR_NAME      TGRAPH
5716222    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001672
```

Results should be like this:

```
RID        KEYWORD          VALUE
5716220    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716220    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 3797.68             
5716220    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716220    CHECK_NUMBER     67714                 
5716220    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716220    EVENT_CODE_1     141107NVCC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE_2     141107NVCC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE_3     141113FLRC            
5716220    EVENT_CODE_4     141031INRA            
5716220    EVENT_CODE_5     141107MSAM            
5716220    EVENT_CODE_6     141113SCRCO           
5716220    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133619\0
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_1 DB791094              
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_2 791094                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_3 792456                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_4 789983                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_5 791910                
5716220    INVOICE_NUMBER_6 792452                
5716220    VENDOR_NAME      VTECH                 
5716220    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001685               

5716221    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716221    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 3797.68             
5716221    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716221    CHECK_NUMBER     67714                 
5716221    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716221    EVENT_CODE_1     141113SCRCO           
5716221    EVENT_CODE_2     141113AZRAR           
5716221    EVENT_CODE_3     141104MORER           
5716221    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133619\1
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER_1 792959                
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER_2 792508                
5716221    INVOICE_NUMBER_3 790437                
5716221    VENDOR_NAME      VTECH                 
5716221    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001685               

5716222    BANK_NUMBER      17                    
5716222    CHECK_AMOUNT     $ 7782.73             
5716222    CHECK_DATE       141211                
5716222    CHECK_NUMBER     67711                 
5716222    DOC_NAME         Expense-Check         
5716222    EVENT_CODE_1                             
5716222    EVENT_CODE_2                             
5716222    FILENAME         Q:\teleform\00133616\0
5716222    INVOICE_NUMBER_1 150562                
5716222    INVOICE_NUMBER_2 150533                
5716222    VENDOR_NAME      TGRAPH
5716222    VENDOR_NUMBER    1001672
```

The structure of the table is as shown above. The data is coming from the same table that needs updating.

Comment: What's the criteria for sorting them? For example, why is `EC_1 71103CTRC` and `EC_2  71027TNRF`, and not: `EC_2  71103CTRC` and `EC_1  71027TNRF` ??

Comment: @Ditto, none, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with w_data as (
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('BANK_NUMBER   ') keyword, rtrim('17                    ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('CHECK_AMOUNT  ') keyword, rtrim('$ 3797.68             ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('CHECK_DATE    ') keyword, rtrim('141211                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('CHECK_NUMBER  ') keyword, rtrim('67714                 ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('DOC_NAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Expense-Check         ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141107NVCC            ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141107NVCC            ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141113FLRC            ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141031INRA            ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141107MSAM            ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141113SCRCO           ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('FILENAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Q:\teleform\00133619\0') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('DB791094              ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('791094                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('792456                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('789983                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('791910                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('792452                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NAME   ') keyword, rtrim('VTECH                 ') value from dual union all
        select 5716220 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NUMBER ') keyword, rtrim('1001685               ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('BANK_NUMBER   ') keyword, rtrim('17                    ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('CHECK_AMOUNT  ') keyword, rtrim('$ 3797.68             ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('CHECK_DATE    ') keyword, rtrim('141211                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('CHECK_NUMBER  ') keyword, rtrim('67714                 ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('DOC_NAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Expense-Check         ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141113SCRCO           ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141113AZRAR           ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('141104MORER           ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('FILENAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Q:\teleform\00133619\1') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('792959                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('792508                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('790437                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NAME   ') keyword, rtrim('VTECH                 ') value from dual union all
        select 5716221 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NUMBER ') keyword, rtrim('1001685               ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('BANK_NUMBER   ') keyword, rtrim('17                    ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('CHECK_AMOUNT  ') keyword, rtrim('$ 7782.73             ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('CHECK_DATE    ') keyword, rtrim('141211                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('CHECK_NUMBER  ') keyword, rtrim('67711                 ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('DOC_NAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Expense-Check         ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('                      ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('EVENT_CODE    ') keyword, rtrim('                      ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('FILENAME      ') keyword, rtrim('Q:\teleform\00133616\0') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('150562                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('INVOICE_NUMBER') keyword, rtrim('150533                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NAME   ') keyword, rtrim('TGRAPH                ') value from dual union all
        select 5716222 rid, rtrim('VENDOR_NUMBER ') keyword, rtrim('1001672               ') value from dual
     )
 select rid,
        CASE WHEN keyword in ( 'EVENT_CODE', 'INVOICE_NUMBER' ) 
           THEN 
              keyword || '_' || row_number() over (partition by rid, keyword order by value )
           ELSE
              keyword
        END keyword,
        value
   from ( select rid, keyword, value,
                count(*) over (partition by rid, keyword) rcount
           from w_data
         )
  /

         RID KEYWORD                        VALUE
  ---------- ------------------------------ ----------------------
     5716220 BANK_NUMBER                    17
     5716220 CHECK_AMOUNT                   $ 3797.68
     5716220 CHECK_DATE                     141211
     5716220 CHECK_NUMBER                   67714
     5716220 DOC_NAME                       Expense-Check
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_1                   141031INRA
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_2                   141107MSAM
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_3                   141107NVCC
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_4                   141107NVCC
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_5                   141113FLRC
     5716220 EVENT_CODE_6                   141113SCRCO
     5716220 FILENAME                       Q:\teleform\00133619\0
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_1               789983
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_2               791094
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_3               791910
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_4               792452
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_5               792456
     5716220 INVOICE_NUMBER_6               DB791094
     5716220 VENDOR_NAME                    VTECH
     5716220 VENDOR_NUMBER                  1001685
     5716221 BANK_NUMBER                    17
     5716221 CHECK_AMOUNT                   $ 3797.68
     5716221 CHECK_DATE                     141211
     5716221 CHECK_NUMBER                   67714
     5716221 DOC_NAME                       Expense-Check
     5716221 EVENT_CODE_1                   141104MORER
     5716221 EVENT_CODE_2                   141113AZRAR
     5716221 EVENT_CODE_3                   141113SCRCO
     5716221 FILENAME                       Q:\teleform\00133619\1
     5716221 INVOICE_NUMBER_1               790437
     5716221 INVOICE_NUMBER_2               792508
     5716221 INVOICE_NUMBER_3               792959
     5716221 VENDOR_NAME                    VTECH
     5716221 VENDOR_NUMBER                  1001685
     5716222 BANK_NUMBER                    17
     5716222 CHECK_AMOUNT                   $ 7782.73
     5716222 CHECK_DATE                     141211
     5716222 CHECK_NUMBER                   67711
     5716222 DOC_NAME                       Expense-Check
     5716222 EVENT_CODE_1
     5716222 EVENT_CODE_2
     5716222 FILENAME                       Q:\teleform\00133616\0
     5716222 INVOICE_NUMBER_1               150533
     5716222 INVOICE_NUMBER_2               150562
     5716222 VENDOR_NAME                    TGRAPH
     5716222 VENDOR_NUMBER                  1001672

  46 rows selected.
```

[edit] updated based on below coments. and to better match expected results[/edit]

the WITH clause is just creating your data ... you can leave it out and change the "from w_data" to your table.

Inner query just grabs the data and counts how many occurances in each "group" of distinct keywords.

Outer query uses CASE to tack on the counter only to EVENT_CODE and INVOICE_NUMBER.
The new column there uses row_number for each group and slices it all together.

You could throw that query back into a MERGE statement for easiest way to update:

```
  MERGE INTO <yourtable>  base
     USING ( <query above>
           ) new
        ON ( new.rid = base.rid
           and new.value = base.value
           and new.original_keyword = base.keyword )
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET base.keyword = new.keyword
  /
```

Comment: That query adds the numerator on every keyword.

Comment: Getting `Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "BASE"."KEYWORD"`

Comment: Also, look at the results I get from your select above...And that is just one of the keywords. I have thousands of RIDs like this.

Comment: @MB34: hmm, I read your initial request as "do this for each RID that has > 1 VALUE" .. but I noticed now you also state only for EC and INVOICE_NUM ... ok, that just needs to be added to WHERE clause ... (I've updated the query to include this)

Comment: @MB34: as for MERGE ... I can't really help unless you post complete table definitions ... (ie CREATE TABLE scripts, INSERTs, etc ... )  It already took me a lot of time to build that fake with clause ... give me something to work with and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: One more thing I see is that the "incrementer" needs to reset for each changed RID value. I am posting 3 more records of data above to illustrate.

Comment: @MB34: Oh, I see .. yeah, this line needs to include RID: `count(*) over (partition by rid, keyword) rcount`  I'll update my query

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below one helps:

```
declare
INCR NUMBER:=1;
INCR1 NUMBER:=1;
CNT_EC NUMBER;
CNT_INV NUMBER;
begin
SELECT COUNT(KEYWORD) INTO CNT_EC FROM TABLE WHERE KEYWORD='EC';
SELECT COUNT(KEYWORD) INTO CNT_INV FROM TABLE WHERE KEYWORD='INVOICE_NUM';
IF CNT_EC>1THEN
FOR I IN(SELECT rid,keyword,value from table where rid>1 and keyword='EC') LOOP
UPDATE TABLE SET KEYWORD=I.KEYWORD||'_'||INCR  AND KEYWORD=I.KEYWORD AND VALUE=I.VALUE and rid=i.rid;
INCR:=INCR+1;
END LOOP;
END IF;
IF CNT_INV>1 THEN 
FOR J IN(SELECT rid,keyword,value from table where rid>1 and keyword='INVOICE_NUM') LOOP
UPDATE TABLE SET KEYWORD=J.KEYWORD||'_'||INCR1  AND KEYWORD=J.KEYWORD AND VALUE=J.VALUE and rid=j.rid;
INCR:=INCR1+1;
END LOOP;
END IF;
END;
```

**

Comment: That works 'somewhat'. you had one mistake in the code and it sets the every EC keyword and every INVOICE_NUM keyword the same for the same RID.

Comment: @Preethi: basic rule of thumb: Try to avoid using PL/SQL if you can do it in SQL  ;)